# For Loop in Function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, for-loop

I'm trying to shift some codes from my main function to a function called read but somehow the loop breaks and it doesn't go through my csv file.
Below are the 2 scripts and the csv.

Thank you for your advice and tips as the learning curve is getting steeper and steeper

---Code Below---

The script 'NotinFunct' will read the csv file and returns this data

[image]

The script 'InFunct' will read the same csv file but only returns one set a data
[image]

The 'NotinFunct' is

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import csv

FILE = 'C://shared//API//NADEV-Numbers_20190220-092956.csv'
NBS = {'5684', '7445477'}
NEW_NBS = {'56847', '74454773'}

def main():
    fields_route = {'Pattern', 'CalledX', 'CalledPrefix', 'CallingX', 'CallingPrefix'}
    for row in csv.DictReader(open(FILE)):
        if row['Type'] == 'RoutePattern':
            for nb in NBS:
                for field in fields_route:
                    if nb in row[field]:
                        for new in NEW_NBS:
                            if nb in new:
                                rp = row['Pattern']

                                pt = row['Partition']

                                newrp = row['Pattern'].replace(nb, new)

                                if row['CalledX'] == 'None':
                                    cedp = row['CalledX'].replace('None', '')
                                else:
                                    cedp = row['CalledX'].replace(nb, new)

                                if row['CalledPrefix'] == 'None':
                                    pced = row['CalledPrefix'].replace('None', '')
                                else:
                                    pced = row['CalledPrefix'].replace(nb, new)

                                if row['CallingX'] == 'None':
                                    cingp = row['CallingX'].replace('None', '')
                                else:
                                    cingp = row['CallingX'].replace(nb, new)

                                if row['CallingPrefix'] == 'None':
                                    pcing = row['CallingPrefix'].replace('None', '')
                                else:
                                    pcing = row['CallingPrefix'].replace(nb, new)

                                print(rp)
                                print(pt)
                                print(newrp)
                                print(cedp)
                                print(pced)
                                print(cingp)
                                print(pcing)
                                print('################')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

the 'InFunct' is

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import csv

FILE = 'C://shared//API//NADEV-Numbers_20190220-092956.csv'
NBS = {'5684', '7445477'}
NEW_NBS = {'56847', '74454773'}

def read():
    fields_route = {'Pattern', 'CalledX', 'CalledPrefix', 'CallingX', 'CallingPrefix'}
    for row in csv.DictReader(open(FILE)):
        if row['Type'] == 'RoutePattern':
            for nb in NBS:
                for field in fields_route:
                    if nb in row[field]:
                        for new in NEW_NBS:
                            if nb in new:
                                rp = row['Pattern']

                                pt = row['Partition']

                                newrp = row['Pattern'].replace(nb, new)

                                if row['CalledX'] == 'None':
                                    cedp = row['CalledX'].replace('None', '')
                                else:
                                    cedp = row['CalledX'].replace(nb, new)

                                if row['CalledPrefix'] == 'None':
                                    pced = row['CalledPrefix'].replace('None', '')
                                else:
                                    pced = row['CalledPrefix'].replace(nb, new)

                                if row['CallingX'] == 'None':
                                    cingp = row['CallingX'].replace('None', '')
                                else:
                                    cingp = row['CallingX'].replace(nb, new)

                                if row['CallingPrefix'] == 'None':
                                    pcing = row['CallingPrefix'].replace('None', '')
                                else:
                                    pcing = row['CallingPrefix'].replace(nb, new)

    return rp, pt, newrp, cedp, pced, cingp, pcing

def main():

    for test in read():
        print(test)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

the csv is

```
Type,Pattern,Partition,Description,CalledX,CalledPrefix,CallingX,CallingPrefix,FwdAll,FwdBusyInt,FwdBusyExt,FwdNAnsInt,FwdNAnsExt,FwdNCovInt,FwdNCovExt,FwdCTIFail,FwdURegInt,FwdURegExt,ExtPNMask,Device
DirectoryNumber,875423,a_nothing_partition,a_nothing_DN,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,11,22,33,44,55,66,744547722,77,88,99,9898,SEP798798465143
DirectoryNumber,5684001,a_nothing_partition,None,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,N/A,N/A
TranslationPattern,568412,a_nothing_partition,a_nothing_tp,None,None,None,5236,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A
TranslationPattern,568411,a_nothing_partition,a_nothing_tp,None,None,875421,None,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A
TranslationPattern,744547720,a_nothing_partition,a_nothing_tp,961433,None,None,None,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A
TranslationPattern,744547721,a_nothing_partition,a_nothing_tp,None,786512,None,None,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A
TranslationPattern,47852,a_nothing_partition,a_nothing_tp,None,None,744547711,None,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A
TranslationPattern,9632,a_nothing_partition,a_nothing_tp,None,None,None,5684,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A
TranslationPattern,897435496,a_nothing_partition,a_nothing_tp,568433,None,None,None,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A
TranslationPattern,7896312145697,a_nothing_partition,a_nothing_tp,None,7445477,None,None,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A
RoutePattern,6568433,a_nothing_partition,None,None,None,None,None,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A
RoutePattern,6568434,a_nothing_partition,None,None,None,None,None,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A
RoutePattern,24132,a_nothing_partition,a_nothing_rp,None,None,7445477,None,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A
HuntPilot,568444,a_nothing_partition,a_nothing_hunt pilot,88,99,66,77,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A
CingPartyX,8787,a_nothing_partition,a_nothing_calling party X,N/A,N/A,11,744547722,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A
CedPartyX,98563,a_nothing_partition,a_nothing_called party X,N/A,N/A,568496,None,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A
```

Comment: It's very unclear what exactly the problem is. Please explain the problem and reduce this down to a [mcve] °

Comment: Actually, the code is complete and verifiable, just not very minimal :^)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `read` function only returns one set of values (the last one).  If you changed the function to a generator you can get all the values.

Change the end of the `read` function to the following, making sure to align the `yield` to the innermost loop block:

```
...

if row['CallingPrefix'] == 'None':
    pcing = row['CallingPrefix'].replace('None', '')
else:
    pcing = row['CallingPrefix'].replace(nb, new)

yield rp, pt, newrp, cedp, pced, cingp, pcing
```

Then you get:

```
('6568433', 'a_nothing_partition', '65684733', '', '', '', '')
('6568434', 'a_nothing_partition', '65684734', '', '', '', '')
('24132', 'a_nothing_partition', '24132', '', '', '74454773', '')
```

Change your `main` function to the following to get similar output to `NotInFunct`:

```
def main():
    for test in read():
        for col in test:
            print(col)
        print('################')
```

Output:

```
6568433
a_nothing_partition
65684733




#################
6568434
a_nothing_partition
65684734




#################
24132
a_nothing_partition
24132


74454773

#################
```